# How do I download PDF from Firebase in Android app which get open only in that particular app?

Tags: android, firebase

I am creating an android app which delivers PDF file for this i am using Firebase ,how should i download that PDF file and only get show in my app PLEASE help me to do this.

Comment: Which part of implementing this use-case do you have problems with? Please share a [minimal reproduction of your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: hello sir, actually i am new to Firebase i want the Firebase codes to download a saved PDF file in Firebase by clicking on an Imagebutton on my android app

Comment: That's a neat requirement for an app. I recommend starting with the [documentation on uploading files to Firebase Storage from Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files). And then the [documentation on downloading files to Firebase Storage from Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files).